# What type have multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am writing own 2d matrix class. I want to design the use of this class much close to real math notation. For example I want access to element as ***matrix[3, 6]***. But c++ didn`t give this ability, but I could access to base multidimensional array in the next way:

```
int matrix[2][2] = {};
int val = matrix[1][0];
```

So I decided to make function that return the base array. For this role the best function will be operator(). So I can access in next way: matrix()[1][0]. Ok, I started to implement it and stuck :(. Look what I have:

```
template <typename ValType>
class Matrix2D
{
protected:
    ValType m_data[2][2] = {};

public:
    ValType** operator()()  // <--- what type?
    {
        return m_data;
    }
}
```

But I received compiler error in function above

> error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'double [2][2]' to 'double **'

I understand error but no have idea what I must change to avoid this error? What type the function must to return?

Comment: "I understand error but no have idea what I must change to avoid this error?" - which means you don't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c for more info about arrays. Basically, arrays are not pointers, and an arrays of arrays are not a pointers to pointer.

Comment: Aside: a common solution to your underlying problem is to overload `()` so that you index the array with `matrix(3,6)`. Another common solution is to overload `[]` so that `matrix[3]` returns something you can apply `[]` to. Another alternative is to make a custom type to represent multidimensional indices, and then you could write `matrix[index(3,6)]`.

Comment: @Hurkyl Those *are* common solutions, which is why they are what I wrote as an answer to this question...

Comment: @barry you did miss one: the indexing type.

Comment: @Yakk Yeah because I don't like that one.

Comment: @barry have you seen the array view "generate an index iterator that visits every element and is random access"?  It can grow on you.

Comment: @Yakk LInk please? I am skeptical.

Comment: @barry  n3851 ts for c++1z.  Should be easy to google: getting link on phone is tricky, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is tagged C++11, you should use `std::array`. And use the indexing operator, not the call operator:

```
template <typename ValType>
class Matrix2D
{
protected:
    using Row = std::array<ValType, 2>;
    std::array<Row, 2> m_data;

public:
    Row& operator[](size_t idx)
    {
        return m_data[idx];
    }
};
```

This way you can just write `matrix[1][0]` instead of having to write `matrix()[1][0]`  (which, frankly, looks like a typo).

Additionally, if you prefer to do both indices simultaneously, you could write your call operator to simply take both:

```
ValueType& operator()(size_t x, size_t y) {
    return m_data[x][y];
}
```

That will allow you `matrix(1, 0)` as an alternative to `matrix[1][0]`.

Comment: Hmmm, looks good.......but what about performance? Are there are would great difference in performance with native arrays?

Comment: @AeroSun Exactly identical.

Answer (score 6):

A 2D array decays to a pointer to its first "line". The following should work:

```
typedef ValType Line[2];

Line* operator()()
{
    return m_data;
}
```

You can get indexing to work in a similar way:

```
ValType* operator[](int line)
{
    return m_data[line];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What type you will select depends on you.:) For example

```
ValType ( * operator()() )[2] 
{
    return m_data;
}
```

When an array is returned by value from a function it is implicitly converted to pointer to its frist element. You have a two-dimensional array declared like

```
ValType m_data[2][2] = {};
```

So its element in turn a one-dimensional array of type `ValType[2]`. Thus  a pointer to such an object (the first element of the array) will be declared like

```
ValType ( *p )[2] = m_data;
```

---

Or

```
ValType ( & operator()() )[2][2] 
{
    return m_data;
}
```

In this case the function returns reference to the array. Functions may not return arrays themselvez but they may return references to arrays. You can use the functuon the following way

```
ValType( &a )[2][2] = obj(); // where obje is an object of the template class
```

Or you can write simpler

```
auto &a = obj();
```

---

Or even like

```
ValType ( * operator()() )[2][2] 
{
    return &m_data;
}
```

This use case looks similarly to the first use case except that the function returns a pointer to the whole array.

---

Of cource in all three cases you could use some typedefs that make the code simpler. But in any case you need to know the syntx I showed.

Take into account that there must be a semicolon after the closing brace of the class definition.:)

Comment: While technically well-defined, this is the sort of thing you should never write and should use typedefs to make it less obscure.

Comment: @Hurkyl  The purpose is to show the new correct syntax for the author of the topic that he does not yet know.

Comment: hmmm.....on MSVS2013 it didn`t works... Where I could read more about this new future?

Comment: @AeroSun  These member function definitions compile successfully even with MS VC++ 2010. It is evident that you simply typed incorrectly your code.

Comment: This looks interesting but your level of detail makes this more than obscure. Can you please give a little more detail on the background of the technique you are using here?

Comment: @user1978011: The first example is, for example, the same thing that [fred](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29870442/1084944) wrote, just without using the typedef to make the syntax sane.